# WGET Localhost 0 bytes

Tags: web-server, cron, localhost, wget, xml

Hi I am trying to execute wget locally using cron, I have been told by my hosting that due to a local loopback that this won't work?

I am attempting the following command:

```
wget -q -O /pathtofile/blah.xml "http://myurl/myfeed.php?id=26"
```

What I am trying to do here is take the output (rss) and save this on my webserver as xml, the way I have been doing this is to open the url and save the source to xml and upload, so I would like to automate this.

Error text:

```
--12:38:58-- http://www.myurl.com/mydir/myfeed.php?id=26
=> `myfeed.php?id=26'
Resolving www.myurl.com... myip
Connecting to www.myurl.com|myip|:80... failed: Connection refused.
```

**Is there any thing I can do to achieve this?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can also try to use the --bind-address option.

```
  --bind-address=ADDRESS
       When making client TCP/IP connections, bind to ADDRESS on the local machine. ADDRESS may be specified as a hostname or IP
       address.  This option can be useful if your machine is bound to multiple IPs.
```

and bind to the external ip, instead of the local one.

Comment: Hi Thanks this is almost working, I get the default RSS but the bind is dismissing the php id variable any ideas?

/usr/bin/wget -q -O blah.xml --bind-address=127.0.0.1 "http://www.myurl.com/mydir/myfeed.php?id=26"

Answer (score 0):

If you can modify `myfeed.php` to take command line variables as well as $_POST/$_GET then you can just execute PHP from cron:

```
php /path/to/myfeed.php --id=26
```

See [here](http://sg.php.net/cli) for more info on passing args to command line PHP.

You will need to do something like this at the top of your file:

```
define('CLI', php_sapi_name() == 'cli');

if(CLI){
   $input =& $argv;
}else{
  $input =& $_POST;
}

if(isset($input['id'])) // etc...
```

Answer (score 0):

It will work if:

1. Your web-server is listening on the local interface; and
2. Your /etc/hosts file has www.myurl.com pointing to the local IP.

Otherwise, it will fail. If you can do a `netstat -untap` and confirm that your web-server is listening on the local interface, it should work.